# Trying to add OpenGl in my project but i get error in setcontentview()

Tags: android, android-layout

My Main Game activity class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class SFGame extends Activity{

    SFGameView gameview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gameview= new SFGameView(this);
        Log.d("ashwin", "wrong");
        setContentView(gameview);
    }

}
```

My SFGameView class code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class SFGameView extends GLSurfaceView{

    public SFGameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

I found out that the error is occurring when I try to call `setContentView(gameview)` from the class `SFGameView`.

Is it necessary to add this `class SFGameView extends GLSUrfaceView` also in the manifest like services? If yes then how?

The manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ku.starfighter.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="Sfmainmenu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
     <activity android:name="SFGame"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <service android:name="SFMusic"></service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a renderer for the GLSurfaceView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html

```
GLSurfaceView.setRenderer(renderer);
```

The implementing `Renderer` class will handle all drawing-related activities.

Edited:
No need to add anything in the manifest file

Comment: thankyou sir... bt i didnt get you. can  you elaborate please.
Where should I set the below code...in SFGameView Class??
I did set but, what is renderer.
GLSurfaceView.setRenderer(renderer);

Comment: The implementing class of the `Renderer` interface serves as the class that will do all the drawing to the `GLSurfaceView`. It has 3 callback functions `onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)`, `onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)` and `onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)`. The `GL10` object allows you to issue GL10 commands/functions and applies it to the GLSurfaceView.